# How to rectify wrong hours mentioned in contract after discovering it 6 months onwards?

Tags: united-kingdom, work-time, contractors

I been working with a company as a contractor for 6 months, now there is a new requirement to fill timesheet of "How many hours I spend in office", and fill in the previous (January) month as well. Turns out, my hours were wrongly mentioned in the contract as it said:

> Total of 37.5 hours. Mon-Thu : 9-5:30 and Friday: 9am-3pm

If we do the maths, it is 40 hours. So technically, I was doing more hours for the last 6 months, the first contract was 3 months, then I signed a new contract.

I did raise this with my manager, as the CEO makes the contract he said he will talk to the CEO but what options do I have. Can I ask them to pay me overtime, or take those hours off by working less for the next few months? What if my CEO says it was a human mistake because everyone works from 9 - 5:30, and that you are getting paid for it?

What are my options?

Comment: UK law says you get a lunchbreak for shifts 6 hours or more. 5x30 mins is 2.5 hours, making 37.5 hours a week. They probably assume that your contract entity is granting you these rights.

Comment: I do get 30 min break. but how u calculate? do you add break into hours? Can you explain more?

Comment: You are not paid for lunch. That makes it 37.5 hours. 8+8+8+8+5.5=37.5

Comment: @JohnHC you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not paid for lunch. That makes it 37.5 hours.

```
Mon: 8.5 - 0.5 =  8
Tue: 8.5 - 0.5 =  8
Wed: 8.5 - 0.5 =  8
Thu: 8.5 - 0.5 =  8
Fri: 6   - 0.5 =  5.5
Total:           37.5
```

Comment: Ah, I never knew we don't get paid for lunch. so do one fill 3.7 hours in each day or 8?

Comment: @cookieMonster Fill in 8 hours Mo-Th, then 5.5 on Fri

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks, that maths was hurting my head.

Comment: @JohnHC: What to fill in very much depends from company to company. At my current client, that would be considered fraudulent behavior as I did not effectively work 8 hours Mon-Thu and the Jira ticket timestamps back that claim up. I'm aware it's a zero-sum-game when you bill weekly (or monthly) but that doesn't mean the client isn't a stickler for these things.

Comment: @Flater and they are always happy to pay for those 10 minutes extra when they need them after 17.30 etc